# How to add a track to Library in Apple Music using Apple Script

Tags: itunes, applescript, music

I searched through a few posts online and most of them say to use this:

```
tell application "Music"
    duplicate current track to source "Library"
end tell
```

...but I get the following error:

`"Music got an error: Can’t set source \"Library\" to current track." number -10006 from source "Library"`

Did Apple change/remove adding a track to the Library? I can't find any update on this and Apple's docs on this are nonexistent.

Comment: In which macOS version are you trying this, or which iTunes version?

Comment: I suggest you get Script Debugger (https://latenightsw.com/sd7/download/) and use its "Explorer" to look at all the properties that iTunes knows about. Or could run `get source "Library"` and then look at all the properties in SD. That might help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of a Mac at the moment, so can't test this, but what happens if you try the following:

```
tell application "Music"

    set newFile to (choose file with prompt "Select track you want to add...")

end tell
```

Of course, you can change the 'prompt' text to whatever you want.

Also, in case you're wanting to, you should be able to get the script to add the track to a specific playlist by adding the following line after the `set newFile` line:

```
add newFile to playlist "Newly added tracks"
```

Of course, you can change the 'playlist' name by changing the text within the quotation marks to whatever you want.